# How to get the list of objects from UI in Spring..?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have shown the arraylist values on UI. Arraylist contain the pojo class "Preference" The Preference class has 3 String members PreferenceName,PreferenceType and PreferenceValue.
In jsp i iterated the arraylist and shown the PreferenceName   , and it's value (shown using radiobutton) wheather it is true or false.
Now when user submit the form . I want arraylist containing the values.I am using Spring. I am getting the other values but is there any way to get the arraylist values. So what i need to do..?

```
                        <c:forEach items="${preferences.preferenceList}" var="preference">
                             <tr height="35px" bgcolor="#fafafa" bordercolor="#FFF">
                                <td width="50%"><c:out value="${preference.preferenceName}"/></td>
                                <td width="20%">
                                    <c:if test="${preference.preferenceType=='boolean'}">
                                     <c:if test="${preference.preferenceValue=='true'}">
                                        <input type="radio" name="${preference.preferenceName}" value="true" checked="true">Yes &nbsp;
                                        <input type="radio" name="${preference.preferenceName}" value="false" >No &nbsp;
                                     </c:if>
                                      <c:if test="${preference.preferenceValue=='false'}">
                                        <input type="radio" name="${preference.preferenceName}" value="true" > Yes &nbsp;
                                        <input type="radio" name="${preference.preferenceName}" value="false" checked="true" >No 
                                       </c:if>
                                    </c:if>
                                </td>
                             </tr>
                         </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<c:forEach items="${preferences.preferenceList}" var="preference" varStatus="itemRow">
    <c:set var="varPath" value="preferenceList[${itemRow.index}]"/>
    <tr height="35px" bgcolor="#fafafa" bordercolor="#FFF">
        <td width="50%">
            <form:label path="${varPath}.preferenceName">${preference.preferenceName}</form:label>
        </td>
        <td width="20%">
            <c:if test="${preference.preferenceType=='boolean'}">
                <form:radiobutton path="${varPath}.preferenceValue" value="true">Yes</form:radiobutton>
                <form:radiobutton path="${varPath}.preferenceValue" value="false">No</form:radiobutton>
            </c:if>
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```